# How to link two files using header file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to link two files. Means, there are files "file1.c" and "file2.c".

file1.c

```
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"stdio.h"
 void function1(int a)
 {
printf("hello I am file%d.c\n ", a);
  }
 void main()
 {
 function1(1);
  }
```

file2.c

```
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"stdio.h"
#include"file.h"
void function2(int b)
{
 printf("hello I am file%d.c\n", b);
 }
int main()
{
 function2(2);
 function1(1);
 }
```

Then I make a header file file.h as

```
#ifndef hell
#define hell
 void function1(int a);
#endif
```

When I compile file2.c as "gcc  file2.c file1.c -o file2
" it gives following error

```
/tmp/cc4tno9R.o: In function `main':
 file1.c:(.text+0x24): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccL4fEki.o:file2.c:(.text+0x24): first defined here
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to write in header file? Is there any error in header file?
Or error in file2.c?

And what about extern? Is it uses for same purpose?

Comment: You can only have 1 main! Otherweise the program don't know where to start?!?

Comment: To start, replace `#include"stdlib.h"`,etc to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Google for their usage. Or better, read a book.

Comment: As said by many, when compiling to assembler, the label `main` is used to make the executable starting. You cannot have more than a `main` in an compiled executable. If you want two executables (one for each main) you can use the makefile I made for this purpose. It exists others projects like this, but for this one, I can show you how to  configure it, just ask me. https://github.com/carrieje/maky

Answer (score 4):

Say that the directory structure is like:

```
                  Project
                     |
       ------------------------------
      |              |              |
    csource        output         header
      |              |              |
    *.c files    executable      .h files
                   files
```

Now, put these two `.c files` inside the `source` folder.

**function.c**

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mymath.h>

int main(void)
{
    int result = sum(11, 19);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Put this header file inside `header` folder.

**mymath.h**

```
#ifndef _MyMath_H__
#define _MyMath_H__
int sum(int, int);
#endif
```

**COMPILATION:**

Firstly, we will compile `function.c` file and create one `object file` with `.o` extension, as follows:

```
C:\Mine\C\test\project>gcc -o output\function.o -c source\function.c
```

On Cygwin:

```
Gagandeep Bali@LAPTOP ~/c/Mine/C/test/project
$ gcc -o output/function.o -c source/function.c
```

Since, `function.c` doesnot contains a `main` method, hence, we will simply use the `-c` option, to only create an `object file`.

Here, the use of `-I` option, basically tells the compiler, where to look for **include** files. Since, we are defining our `header` folder, hence, you can use `#include <mymath.h>` instead of `#include "mymath.h". Now we will compile the`main.c` file as:

```
C:\Mine\C\test\project>gcc -o output\main -I header\ -Wall source\main.c output\function.o
```

On Cygwin:

```
Gagandeep Bali@LAPTOP ~/c/Mine/C/test/project
$ gcc -o output/main -I header/ -Wall source/main.c output/function.o
```

Now one can run it, like:

```
C:\Mine\C\test\project>.\output\main
Result: 30
```

On Cygwin:

```
Gagandeep Bali@LAPTOP ~/c/Mine/C/test/project
$ ./output/main
Result: 30
```

You can also, create static and dynamic libraries, of custom functions, that you can use. I just know, how to create a static library.

If you wanted to create a static library, of your own, simply first put all `object files` inside the library. Create another folder, say `library` for this purpose. Now add all `.o` files inside the library, like this:

```
Gagandeep Bali@LAPTOP ~/c/Mine/C/test/project
$ ar cr library/mymathlibrary.a output/function.o
```

Now simply compile program like:

```
Gagandeep Bali@LAPTOP ~/c/Mine/C/test/project
$ gcc -Wall source/main.c library/mymathlibrary.a -o output/main -I header
```

And run as previously described.

Comment: Thanks and what about "extern"? Is extern used for the same purpose too?

Comment: @user3717474: Actually every function is `extern` in `C language` by default, IMHO, since we can use any function from any file. You can write the function declaration as `extern int sum(int, int);` to give emphasis, on the fact, that the function definition resides in some other file, other than, where it is being called/used. For the REST, YOU'RE MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to include all library files in the first file. Just save it as a library file with a ".h" extension as a library file and include it in second file, Like shown below.

file1.h

```
void function1(int a) {
    printf("hello I am file%d.c\n ", a);
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"

void function2(int b) {
    printf("hello I am file%d.c\n", b);
}

int main() {
    function2(2);
    function1(1);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So all should look like this:

file1.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(int a) {
    printf("hello I am file%d.c\n ", a);
 }
```

file2.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"

void function2(int b) {
    printf("hello I am file%d.c\n", b);
}

int main() {
    function2(2);
    function1(1);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program `main` is beeing called. If you have 2 definitions of main which one should be called?

There should be one file including `main` and another file including function that you want to use in the first file.